# how to keep the service running in background even after the app is closed/killed?

Tags: android, service

there are many articles written on the topic I specified. However, all are seems to be not working. At least in my case. I just want to run my service all the time even after the app is close manually by user. I don't want foreground service as it display some notification icon in the status bar. I want regular service to complete my requirement. Or please suggest if any other alternative available to achieve this. I tried with `return START_STICKY` as return value for `onStartCommand` call back. I also tried with broadcast receiver which doesn't help me anyway. Please help me on this.

Comment: There no option to run your service in background even after force killed !

Answer (score 1):

You can create the alarm with 5 mins in the onTaskRemoved() method in your service class. It will automatically invoke after the 5mins and restarts the service.

In Service Class

```
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
     Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
     restartService.setPackage(Yourpackagename);
     PendingIntent restartServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
     AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealTime()+1000, restartServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: you can use setExactAlarm() method of alarm manager. That will clear the alarm once its executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by implementing the **AlarmManger** concept in Android. Take a look at following URLs once you will get idea to implement this background service.

Hint: You should make sure about this before implementing. Because it will consume battery a lot.

Good luck

http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want the service to be stopped if the app is uninstalled. But, the Alarm in android will not stop until the phone get boots. Isn't?